# Can one application have two facebook app id with two different fb account?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have published one application which uses facebook login. I have created facebook developer account and get app id for my application and it was working fine. Its been a year I have released my application on google play.

But now I am not able to access my facebook account. I am facing this error "Security check  - This account isn't eligible for this process for MY App name"...

What I am thinking now, is to get new app Id from different fb account and and change that in my application and give update of my application. But my question is, the existing users, who have not taken the updated version can still use facebook login, with previous app id. I mean can my application have two different app id from two different fb account?

Thanks in advance,

Krishna

Comment: There can be different code versions of your Android app, that use different app ids, yes. But you won’t be able to recognize users that logged into the old one in the new one, because they will have different app-scoped user ids. You’d need to add both apps to the same business first to be able to make the connection between those.